# How can I pass an absolute path via the command line to a parameter in XSLT 1.0 (using msxsl.exe)?

Tags: xml, xslt, wix, xslt-1.0, msxsl

I have a WXS file that was generated by WiX's heat utility. I'm trying to modify it with an (existing) **exclusions.xslt** file to automatically exclude certain components based on the contents of another XML file (I'll call this **parts.xml**). The xslt file is currently used to remove some components/files/directories from the installer, but for a relatively static list.

However, for right now, my primary concern is just getting it to load and store the correct path from the parameter and store its contents in a variable.

This is how the transform is applied (once WiX is finished harvesting with heat to a file "before.wxs"):

```
msxsl.exe "before.wxs" "exclusions.xslt" -o "after.wxs" srcroot="$(SrcRoot)"
```

I passed in srcroot to be a parameter within the XSLT file that will be used to find **parts.xml** on the user's machine.

To get the parameter from the command line and replace all back slashes with forward slashes:

```
<!-- Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30153713/5605122 and http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx-->
<xsl:param name="srcroot" />
<xsl:variable name="filename">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="concat('file://', $srcroot, '/foo/parts.xml')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select='\\' />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select='/' />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="myparts" select="document($filename)" />
```

The string-replace-all that I got from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx) is:

```
<!-- XSL 1.0 string-replace-all, taken from: http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx -->
<xsl:template name="string-replace-all">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:param name="replace" />
    <xsl:param name="by" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $replace)">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,$replace)" />
            <xsl:value-of select="$by" />
            <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
                <xsl:with-param name="text"
                select="substring-after($text,$replace)" />
                <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="$replace" />
                <xsl:with-param name="by" select="$by" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

I am getting a rather unhelpful error:

> Code:   0x80004005 Unexpected character in query string.

but if I remove just the code snippets I've posted, the error goes away. I'm not sure how to debug into this and figure out what's going on, but after looking through it, I believe I have a fundamental misunderstanding of what I think should happen, rather than just a typo or syntax error.

Ultimately, I want the contents of parts.xml to be stored in "myparts". What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a parameter `$src` and another `$srcroot`, that should give an error if the snippets are complete.

Comment: Ah oops, that was actually a typo copying it over to here (I renamed it to make it clearer as to what its purpose is). I've edited the question with the fix. The actual file didn't have this typo, but I've changed them all to "srcroot" here. Thanks. It turns out I also missed that to use the code from [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx), I'd have to wrap the strings in both double and single quotes. I'll make the necessary changes and update if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I just needed to set the string literals in single quotes (and the backslash did not need to be escaped). Also my srcroot has a trailing backslash, so I omitted it from the beginning here. Here is the updated code:

```
<!-- Adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/a/30153713/5605122 and http://geekswithblogs.net/Erik/archive/2008/04/01/120915.aspx-->
<xsl:param name="srcroot" />
<xsl:variable name="filename">
    <xsl:call-template name="string-replace-all">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="concat($srcroot, 'foo/parts.xml')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="replace" select="'\'" />
        <xsl:with-param name="by" select="'/'" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:variable>
```

As for the issue of figuring out how to test it, I finally got it to check to see if a file exists by doing the following:

Since I'm using msxsl, I decided to use an extension for a fileExists function:

```
<!-- Adapted from https://www.stylusstudio.com/SSDN/default.asp?action=9&read=2993&fid=48 -->
<msxsl:script language="JScript" implements-prefix="user">
<![CDATA[
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
function fileExists(filename){
return fso.FileExists(filename);
}

// With .NET XSLT processor we need to use the Framework API
//function fileExists(filename){
//return System.IO.File.Exists(filename); 
//} 

]]>
</msxsl:script>
```

Inside a template, I did the following check:

```
<xsl:if test="not( function-available('user:fileExists') )">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:text>Required facilities are not available.</xsl:text>
        </xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

And if that passed, I did the following:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="user:fileExists(string($filename))">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:text>File found! Here:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$filename"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:text>File cannot be found:</xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$filename"/>
        </xsl:message>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

The messages were not output to the console unless I set terminate="yes" for some reason, so this halts the build and I'll have to remove it, but it has helped me debug this and find out that the parameter was successfully received by the XSLT file and that I am able to check if the file at that path exists.